# NavigationDrawerFragment анимация кнопки home

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Я создаю activity с боковой панелью навигации, с помощью стандартных средств android studio. По умолчанию у кнопки home в этом шаблоне анимации нет (превращение списка в стрелку и обратно при открытии и закрытии меню). Может кто-нибудь подсказать, или дать ссылку на пример, как эту анимацию добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать другой импорт

> import android.support.**v7**.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

вместо v4, и исправьте функцию нового конструктора ActionBarDrawerToggle